# Analyzing a BSOD (WinDbg) beyond !analyze -v

Tags: windows, debugging, windbg, bsod

I'm trying to analyze a BSOD (0xFC,ATTEMPTED_EXECUTE_OF_NOEXECUTE_MEMORY) which occurred on a Windows 10 machine during a restart, but I'm stuck.

`!analyze -v` gave useful information like:

```
    DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT
    PROCESS_NAME:  System
    MODULE_NAME: mrxsmb
    IMAGE_NAME:  mrxsmb.sys
    FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0xFC_mrxsmb!MRxSmbQueryLbfoTeamCapability
    BUCKET_ID:  0xFC_mrxsmb!MRxSmbQueryLbfoTeamCapability
    PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  0xFC_mrxsmb!MRxSmbQueryLbfoTeamCapability

        # Child-SP          RetAddr           Call Site
    00 ffffd000`20505ba8 fffff802`a03e1a7c nt!KeBugCheckEx
    01 ffffd000`20505bb0 fffff802`a0319229 nt! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'+0x1377c
    02 ffffd000`20505bf0 fffff802`a031a661 nt!MiSystemFault+0x7e9
    03 ffffd000`20505ce0 fffff802`a03c8bbc nt!MmAccessFault+0x5f1
    04 ffffd000`20505e40 fffff800`1cf70030 nt!KiPageFault+0x13c
    05 ffffd000`20505fd8 fffff802`a072fea2 ndis!_NULL_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR+0x558
    06 ffffd000`20505fe0 fffff802`a07300e6 nt!IopXxxControlFile+0x1162
    07 ffffd000`205061b0 fffff802`a03ca1a3 nt!NtDeviceIoControlFile+0x56
    08 ffffd000`20506220 fffff802`a03c2860 nt!KiSystemServiceCopyEnd+0x13
    09 ffffd000`20506428 fffff800`1d7df2aa nt!KiServiceLinkage
    0a ffffd000`20506430 fffff800`1d818b5b mrxsmb!MRxSmbQueryLbfoTeamCapability+0x16a
    0b ffffd000`20506570 fffff800`1cbc1c7d mrxsmb!MRxSmbPnPBindingHandler+0x1ab
    0c ffffd000`205066e0 fffff800`1cbc2194 TDI!TdiNotifyNewPnpClient+0x12d
    0d ffffd000`20506710 fffff800`1cbc1db0 TDI!TdiExecuteRequest+0x2d4
    0e ffffd000`20506760 fffff800`1cbc184c TDI!TdiHandleSerializedRequest+0x120
    0f ffffd000`205067d0 fffff800`1d7e0b96 TDI!TdiRegisterPnPHandlers+0x12c
    10 ffffd000`20506800 fffff800`1d81ab71 mrxsmb!MRxSmbStartTransport+0xfe
    11 ffffd000`20506890 fffff800`1d228f2f mrxsmb!MRxSmbStart+0x51
    12 ffffd000`205068e0 fffff800`1d816faf rdbss!RxStartMinirdr+0xef
    13 ffffd000`20506930 fffff800`1d7d366e mrxsmb!MRxSmbDevFcbXXXControlFile+0x1eb
    14 ffffd000`205069a0 fffff800`1d2567de mrxsmb!SmbShellDevFcbXXXControlFile+0xe
    15 ffffd000`205069d0 fffff800`1d256665 rdbss!RxXXXControlFileCallthru+0xb6
    16 ffffd000`20506a00 fffff800`1d2694d9 rdbss!RxCommonDevFCBFsCtl+0xa5
    17 ffffd000`20506a50 fffff802`a0367c11 rdbss!RxFspDispatch+0xe9
    18 ffffd000`20506b10 fffff802`a034f399 nt!IopProcessWorkItem+0x81
    19 ffffd000`20506b80 fffff802`a02c3b35 nt!ExpWorkerThread+0xe9
    1a ffffd000`20506c10 fffff802`a03c4b16 nt!PspSystemThreadStartup+0x41
    1b ffffd000`20506c60 00000000`00000000 nt!KiStartSystemThread+0x16
```

These info gave me some idea what went wrong:
The source of the problem might be in the  `mrxsmb!MRxSmbQueryLbfoTeamCapability` function according to WinDbg. 
MRxSMB is the so called "SMB Mini-Redirector". A redirector is a component which is part of a remote file system driver. The rdbss stuff is also part of this redirector architecture which MRxSMB is built on.
The TDI stuff stands for "Transport Driver Interface" and is according to the Windows Internals book some sort of legacy "kernel-mode device driver that implements the kernel-mode portion of a networking API's implementation".

From that I assume Windows tries to access a remote filesystem via SMB. I think it actually tries to access a network drive which is not accessible.
But I'd like to understand why this causes a BSOD.

My questions are:

1. How does WinDbg know that the problem starts with `mrxsmb!MRxSmbQueryLbfoTeamCapability+0x16a` and doesn't occur later?
2. `ndis!_NULL_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR` looks suspicious. According to google such a descriptor marks the end of a loaded library. But why does it then show up as function here?
3. If I take the return address of `ndis!_NULL_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR` (fffff802`a072fea2) and go some bytes back in memory I get this:

```
    1: kd> u fffff802`a072fe90 fffff802`a072fea2
    nt!IopXxxControlFile+0x1150:
    fffff802`a072fe90 eb13            jmp     nt!IopXxxControlFile+0x1165 (fffff802`a072fea5)
    fffff802`a072fe92 488bd7          mov     rdx,rdi
    fffff802`a072fe95 488b8c2488000000 mov     rcx,qword ptr [rsp+88h]
    fffff802`a072fe9d e8fe8dc1ff      call    nt!IofCallDriver (fffff802`a0348ca0)
    fffff802`a072fea2 448be0          mov     r12d,eax
```

Is my assumption correct, that the `ndis!_NULL_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR+0x558` thing happens actually in `nt!IofCallDriver` since that is the last instruction before the return address of `ndis!_NULL_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR+0x558`? But why does this function then not show up in the stack trace?

4. How can I actually get function parameters? From my understanding I can't because the calling convention is that the first 4 parameters are passed in registers rather than the stack and I only have the register contents of the last operation?
5. How to proceed?

Comment: 3) NB:  ub <return address > works great to examine a call 

4) To see some parameters, you can try : http://www.codemachine.com/tool_cmkd.html
And !stack –p  . For me it works great in user mode, never tried it in kernel.

Comment: @KjellGunnar: Thanks a lot, the cmkd.dll is very helpful! :)

Comment: @Thomas Weller: Thanks for your reply! 1) So how is "something interesting" identified? 3) Either I'm blind or I totally get this wrong or both. The return address for the call to `ndis!_NULL_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR` is `fffff802a072fea2`. So I thought that the instruction before that address, must be the call to `ndis!_NULL_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR`. As shown above there is a call to `nt!IofCallDriver` at this address (`fffff802a072fe9d`). So it seems as if this function was called but didn't return, it should therefore show up on the stack.

Comment: @Thomas Weller: I think I did it right, see here: pastebin.com/7ssWVh42 The return address on the stack is the last instruction pointer + 1, isn't it? So the last intruction being executed was the call to `nt!IofCallDriver`. The instruction right after it is the `mov` instruction. Therefore the return address on the stack points to the `mov` instruction. Since the return address is still on the stack, that means the the stack frame for this call still exists, therefore the function hasn't returned.

Comment: @0x80: you're right, sorry. Deleting comments